# ++ or -- Incrementer or Decrementer Speed Comparison

Tags: javascript, performance, time-complexity, increment, decrement

Classmate mentioned to me that he read the *decrementer* **(`--`)** was supposed to perform operations faster than the *incrementer* **(`++`)**.  We ran a test with JavaScript and came up with *mixed results*.

On my *MacBook Pro i5* (mid-2014), `++` was **almost 3 times faster** than `--` when **using the console.time method** to log the difference in *Chrome*, and in *Firefox* `++` just barely edged out `--`.

On *his Windows laptop* (unsure the model), it was nearly the exact opposite with `--` coming in much faster across the browsers.

So what's happening?  Is this hardware or software?  What's the difference and why would either one or the other operate at any greater or lesser speed?

The question here is *why is there a difference on different machines?*  Comparison to 0 would seem like an obvious answer why we're seeing the decrement slower on my MacBook, but it doesn't explain why it's actually faster on the window's machine.

We expected decrement to be slower in both cases and were just testing the difference, then we came up with this strange result.  Hence this question.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be any difference for me.  [JsPerf](http://jsperf.com/incrementvsdecrement)

Comment: I did three tests in milliseconds.
increment: 136, 138, 137
decrement: 319, 269, 261

Comment: @Abhishek Java != JavaScript.

Comment: @UweKeim I know the difference between java and javascript, but I think concepts will remain same, isn't it? :)

Comment: @UweKeim but the "comparison with 0 is faster" reason is probably still valid

Comment: The reason is the same for all languages - if there is any difference at all, the difference is due to the fact that comparison with 0 is faster than equality comparison.